# Error "Connection must be open for this operation" while reading a BLOB from oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, blob

I am trying to retrieve a BLOB value from a oracle database using a stored procedure with output parameters(parm). Here is the piece of code where I do this.

```
using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sStoredProcName))
{
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  AttachParameters(db, cmd, lParamValueList);

  // Open connection
  if (idbTransaction != null)
  {
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, idbTransaction);
  }
  else
  {
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
  }
  // Retrieve any return values
  GetReturnValues(db, conn, cmd, ref lParamValueList);
}
```

And then under GetReturnValues there is another calling function, the piece of troubled code is

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
if (db != null && cmd != null && (Out || IsReturnValue))
{
  int iIndex = ((Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)cmd).Parameters.IndexOf(ParamName);
  if (iIndex >= 0)
  {
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter parm = (((Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)cmd).Parameters[iIndex]);

   if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     conn.Open();

     Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleBlob blob = new Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleBlob((Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection)conn);
     blob = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleBlob)parm.Value;  //<============== Troubled code

     if (blob.Length > 0)
     {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[blob.Length];
       blob.Read(bytes, 0, (int)blob.Length);
       ReturnValueBytes = bytes;
      }
...
```

Everything seems to working fine unless the it reaches the line of the code where I am setting the output parameter value to a ORACLEBLOB variable. I understand that the ORACLE BLOB requires the connection to be opened explicitly. Till the troubled line the BLOB connection state is open and as soon as it passes

```
blob = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleBlob)parm.Value
```

the state of the connection inside the BLOB variable is closed.

I am not able to understand why is this happening. Any hints or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

As it happens most of the time (with me), it was a silly mistake. I was concentrating more on the BLOB variable and almost ignored the rest of the stuff.

I was doing

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

and the connection was getting closed just after this. I changed my code to

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and its working fine now.

Hope this will help someone else and will save some time.

Cheers,
Deepak